# Spelling error in bash, dont know what is the error

Tags: linux, bash

This function is supposed to check if the attribute that we are using "$1" is in a directory "MINIENTREGA_CONF" that contains a bunch of files.

```
function fichero_existe(){
  i=0
  for fichero in ${MINIENTREGA_CONF}; do
    if [ "$fichero" = "$1" ] ; then
      i=1
    fi
  done
  if [ "$i" -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "minientrega.sh: Error, no se pudo realizar la entrega">&2
    echo "minientrega.sh+ no es accesible el fichero \" $1 \"">&2
    return 66
  fi
}
```

Comment: What about using simple `[[ -e $minie/$1 ]]` instead of that whole `for` loop and `eq` thingy?

Comment: How do you call the function? With `fichero_existe "$1"`? Can you `echo  "Look for $1 in ${MINIENTREGA_CONF} "` ?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `MINIENTREGA_CONF` a directory as you mentioned in your question or a variable that contains the name of the directory?

If the former is true

```
function fichero_existe(){
    if [[ ! -e "/path/to/MINIENTREGA_CONF/$1" ]]
    then
        echo "minientrega.sh: Error, no se pudo realizar la entrega">&2
        echo "minientrega.sh+ no es accesible el fichero \" $1 \"">&2
        return 66
    fi
}
```

checks if the file does not exist.

Notice the use of an absolute path so it doesn't matter where you run the script from.

Comment: Yeah, it is a directory that contains some files and i have to check if the file that we put as an arg( the script is called minientrega) like this ./minientrega buena; that file, buena, is the one we are looking for in MINIENTREGA_CONF. thaks for answering i really appreciate if u answer again.

Answer (score -1):

For below line, it should be ==

```
 if [ "$fichero" = "$1" ] ; then
```

Comment: `=` is actually better than `==` :) Anyway, it definitely is not the issue.

Comment: for fichero in ${MINIENTREGA_CONF}/* but you're better off with using find(1).